# Find vs Findstr results

Tags: find, windows-server-2008-r2, findstr

Per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/406708/94278) I was attempting to use findstr to locate a string (a name) inside some HL7 log files in a directory.  Findstr was getting 0 results, but Find returned plenty.  I played around with the syntax of my findstr command, but couldn't get it to return a result.  Note, as these are HL7 files, the name is surrounded by symbols (|, ^, etc.):

```
D:\logs>findstr /l /m /c:"Test" *.*

D:\logs>
```

I assume the lack of output means 0 results.  Meanwhile:

```
D:\logs>find /c "Test" *.*

---------- LOG1.LOG: 0

---------- LOG2.LOG: 4

---------- LOG3.LOG: 0

---------- LOG4.LOG: 0

---------- LOG5.LOG: 8

---------- LOG6.LOG: 0

---------- LOG7.LOG: 18
```

So there are plenty of results.  Why didn't Findstr find any files?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the log file so that I can reproduce?

Comment: @djangofan I'm having issues ginning up fake files for some reason.  Making a small text file with the bare minimum of what I think is a sufficient simulation (e.g. "|Test^Foo") ends up working with findstr.

Comment: I think with those special characters, like '^', you need to enable delayed expansion in your script.  This script is an example I made that uses both FIND and FINDSTR.exe :  http://thegreenoak.blogspot.com/2012/01/dos-batch-script-to-edit-property-files.html .